# Doorbell constantly rings even after replacing switch

Tags: electrical, doorbell

This is a newer home in the US (fewer than 10 years old).  The doorbell started ringing all the time.  Disconnected button and it stopped.  Replaced the button with a new button, and it stayed on all the time again.  Touch the two wires together that connect to the button and it rings, and stops ringing when they are disconnected.

Both the original and replacement buttons were lighted.  In testing the new button with a multi-meter, there was a continuous connection (with some resistance) even when the button was unpressed, and a completed connection with no resistance when it was pressed.

I disassembled the new switch and removed the LED from the circuit, and now it works as expected - ringing the doorbell when the button is depressed, but not ringing when it is not.  But the doorbell is no longer lighted.

What do I need to check (or replace) to allow a lighted switch to work?

Comment: are there only 2 wires?

Comment: measure the resistance backwards; it can change because of the diode. you might be mixing AC and DC... It might be enough for your existing system to inline a resistor with the button to reduce the current used by the LED and thus prevent the bell from detecting a closed circuit, or go the other way, and use a filament bulb to hoard all the current from the bell (depends on your system which will work)

Comment: Only 2 wires.  The resistance was the same each way.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of lighted switches some most work fine on old coil and strike chime but newer electronic chimes require low drain (led) type switches to be lighted or they constantly ring, I had this happen when I switched to an electronic chime from the old strike style. Replacing the incadesent lighted switch with a led lighted switch solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What voltage does the doorbell run on and is the pushbutton rated for the same voltage? Might be mismatched.
Other thought is maybe moisture is getting into the pushbutton which is affecting the led.